# How to update Material-UI theme to change font size of TextField labels, Menu dropdown labels, and Autocomplete labels in a React project?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I am currently working on a React project and using Material-UI for styling my components. I would like to update the theme to change the font size of various labels, specifically the Text Field labels, Menu dropdown labels, and Autocomplete labels.

I have tried searching for a solution, but I haven't been able to find a straightforward answer. I understand that Material-UI provides a theming system that allows customization of various aspects, including typography. However, I'm unsure of the exact steps required to achieve the desired font size changes.

Could someone please guide me through the process of updating the Material-UI theme to change the font size specifically for the labels mentioned above?

Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it, i just test on TextField, it changed fontSize correctly. You can do it with the other components

```
const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
      // Name of the component
      MuiInputBase: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            fontSize: '25px'
          }
        }
      }
    },
  });
```